# MVC 4 get data from model to layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I created an app about employees, when an employee who is admin log in then he get one more menu link about to manage the employees. This links in _layout body header. I want to show that link only u know when the employee is an admin and I wanna do it like I create a class with a bool variable and when someone log in I wanna create an object from that class and set that bool varoable false or true depends on that employee is an admin or not. And when that layout render every time when u change pages that link about manage the employees shows in the menu if the object bool variable is true so the employee is an admin. I'm still new in MVC I was looking for a solve but could find out.

And sry for my English I got no friend with who I can train it.

```
_Layout:
@model namespace.Models.MyModel
...
@if(Model.adminUser){ @Html.ActionLink("UserManagment","Index","Users")

MyModel:
public class MyModel{
public bool adminUser{get;set;}
}

LoginController:
.....
Logic Check that if usern and pw ok and if he is an admin
new MyModel{adminUser=true}
else{
MyModel{adminUser=false}
}
```

Comment: have you tried anything? from what I can tell, you are asking how to do something that is covered in the main MVC tutorials.

Comment: yes i did that thing is the last one i need in that project

Comment: you need to be more specific about what your problem is (with code, preferably).  We can help you understand and fix coding problems, but most people will not write a full program for you to use.

Comment: there are plenty of sites with tutorials, if you are just looking for code to copy into your project. This site isn't one of those, though.

Comment: im sure is it but  what ure doing is not so helpful, u said its in main tutorials so while u wrote me 2 sad comments u could write the answer :(

Comment: write the answer to what? you didn't really ask a question, you asked for someone to give you code.

Comment: I'm more than willing to help, if you have a question that can be answered.  and if I don't know the answer, the suggestions to ways you can improve the question will help to draw others who actually might know the answer.  but in order for someone to provide an answer, there has to be a question that makes sense, and is solvable *without writing the program for you*

Comment: nope , enough if some tells it how to do it , where did u read that i ask for code , im sure its max 30 lines i just dont get it how to do it cuz if i pass viewbag through home index after log in i get that data but thats for one time cuz if i change page it disapear

Comment: i got a method for check that the employee is an admin or not

Comment: since you haven't provided any code for us to work from, how could we provide an answer without writing an entire program first?

Comment: so somehow i have to create an objeck with a bool variable in it and set it true or false depends the employee is ok

Comment: i dont even know what codes should i copy  to know the problem

Comment: and that's exactly why the question is unanswerable.  all we could do is throw code at the screen and say "hmm, you might do it like this if your page is like this, or maybe you could do it like this if you have this, or maybe you might not be able to do this because you have that....".  *You need to be more specific*.  see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/

Comment: how can i get data from exiting object in _layout everytime when its render? cuz if i use model in it it says its null

Comment: now that's a question that might be answerable.  but first, you'd have to show the code that is setting the value in the model, and what the part of your _layout file where you are trying to use the value looks like.

Comment: use the edit option to edit your question, don't try to paste code in comments.

Comment: now do u know what is my problem i mean is it understable?

Comment: I'm guessing that your model has more than just that one property in it; that being said, I don't see why this wouldn't work, unless that pseudo code you have that checks to see if the user is an admin isn't working correctly....

Comment: there's still not really enough code here to know what the problem is, but at least there is a bit of a picture of what you have tried to do.  You show setting that model property in your `LoginController` as a new model, but you aren't showing what action result that model is bound to, and if you are sending that model to any other action results....

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm *guessing* based on your post and comments that this is perhaps what you're looking for(?):

In some `_Layout`:

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
      <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>

    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin"))
     {
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("User Managment","Index","Users")</li> //some privileged link
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Foo Management","Index","Foo")</li> //some privileged link
     }

   </ul>
</div>
```

In the trivial example

- check if `Request.IsAuthenticated`
- *and* that *authenticated* user is in a role (e.g. Admin)
- and only then display the "privileged links"

Above only handles display - you'll have to [protect/restrict your `Controller`/`Actions` appropriately](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

Hth.